# Message loop in MFC

Tags: mfc, message-loop

I have learned a bit about Win32 API, but now I want to learn MFC. In my ebook, they said that the `CWinApp` class manages main thread of application, but I can't find something like `GetMessage`, `DispatchMessage` functions in this class. So how it can begin the messages loop?

Someone explain this for me please. Sorry, I'm a newer in MFC and my English is bad.
And where can I find some ebooks/tutorials about MFC in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

This all done in the `CWinApp:Run` section.

After `InitInstance` returns true, `CWinApp:Run` is launched and the message-loop takes its role. This message-loop is tricky because it also handles `OnIdle` calls when the application has nothing to do.

Just look into the source code.

Answer (score 1):

MFC is somewhat like a wrapped up layer on Win32.   The message loop is wrapped up inside a member of CWinThread called Run. And the application class is derived from CWinApp which is in turn derived from CWinThread.  This method is not generally overridden.  If the message loop code should be read, this method should be overridden and the code can be seen while debugging.   It handles the idle message also

```
int CWinThread::Run()
{
    ....

    for (;;)
    {
        // phase1: check to see if we can do idle work
        while (bIdle &&
            !::PeekMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur), NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            // call OnIdle while in bIdle state
            if (!OnIdle(lIdleCount++))
                bIdle = FALSE; // assume "no idle" state
        }

        // phase2: pump messages while available
        do
        {
            // pump message, but quit on WM_QUIT
            if (!PumpMessage())
                return ExitInstance();

            // reset "no idle" state after pumping "normal" message
            //if (IsIdleMessage(&m_msgCur))
            if (IsIdleMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur)))
            {
                bIdle = TRUE;
                lIdleCount = 0;
            }

        } while (::PeekMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur), NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MFC has simplified message handling by using message-maps, programmer mostly need not to bother how message-loop is running, how messages are delivered, and how mapped-messages map to the user defined functions. I would advice you to fiddle around `CWnd`-derived classes (like frames, dialogs), and see how mapped-messages are calling your functions.

A `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is calling your OnMouseMove, provided you put an entry `ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE` - that's an interesting this you should find how it is working. Playing around with `CWinApp`-derived class isn't good idea.